# Using environment variables to provide shortcuts across multiple OS Versions and architectures

Tags: x86, 64-bit, environment-variables, shortcut, group-policy

This week I was facing a scenario, where regular techniques to deploy shortcuts through GPOs are not sufficent anymore.

I was facing an environment, where XP,7,10 is present in both, 32 bit (x86) and 64 bit (x64) architectures - and multiple languages.

- Many applications can be installed for both architectures (x86 and x64) and run on every system.
- Some Users require both, the x86 and x64 version availbale through different shortcuts.

So, how to efficently create Shortcuts for over 60 automatically distributed applications?

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

Using the well known environment variables like `%programfiles%`, `programfiles(x86)` does not workout anymore, because:

- XP does not know the `programfiles(x86)` variable
- `programfiles` refers to the x86 or x64 folder, based on the architecture of 
  the machine. (Or more specific: To the architecture of the process calling the variable)
- For XP, the name of the 32-bit-folder is localized (I.e. `C:\Programme (x86)` for a german XP, running x64)

Assuming, that there are 2 languages, 2 OS Types (7,10 behave equal regarding "type") and 2 architecture types, the following Options are possible with "native" Tools, but it is already clumsy:

To create a shortcut to the "highest" version, you need to deploy 3 Shortcut "rules":

```
Shortcut |Target                           | Purpose
App      |%programfiles%\App\app.exe       | x86-app on a x86-xp-7-10 or
         |                                 | x64-app on a x64-xp-7-10
App      |%programfiles(x86)%\App\app.exe  | x86-app on a x64-7-10
App      |C:\Programme (x86)\App\app.xe    | x86-app on a x64-xp (german)
```

Assuming, you also want to enable the possibility of every application beeing available as x86 and x64 at the same time, it gets even worse, because: `%programfiles%` will lead to wrong results (it could be either x86 or x64) - So you need WMI-Filters on every "shortcut" beeing created to handle this.

A rule like this:

```
Shortcut |Target                           | Purpose
App 64   |%programfiles%\app\app.exe       | x64-app on a x64-7-10
```

would accidently link the `32 bit version` on `32-bit-systems` with the name `x64` - without some WMI-Filter, deactivating the rule.

So it would be 4 rules, 2 with WMI-Filters:

```
Shortcut |Target                           | Purpose
App 64   |%programfiles%\App\app.exe       | x64-app on a x64-xp-7-10 + wmi-filter
App 32   |%programfiles%\App\app.exe       | x86-app on a x86-xp-7-10 + wmi_filter
App 32   |%programfiles(x86)%\App\app.exe  | x86-app on a x64-7-10 
App 32   |C:\Programme (x86)\App\app.xe    | x86-app on a x64-xp (german)
```

So - 240 shortcut rules, if there is only one "foreign language" - But there where 5 of them -> **480 error prone shortcut rules.** -> Nope!

## The Goal

I wanted to be able to reduce the amount of work required. Just creating (worst-case) 2 entries per shortcut, stating:

- This application can be available anywhere, as 32-bit version.
- This application can be available on 64-bit machines only, as 64 bit version.

## Custom Environment Variables by GPO, using WMI Filters

As a solution to this question, I've created 1 GPO to create the required custom Environment-Variables:

```
Variable | Purpose           
%pf_x86% | Program Files x86 on any system 
%pf_x64% | Program Files x64 on any system (if existing)
```

So, this (single GPO) comes down to a total of 6 rules (+1 for every additional language of XP):

```
Variable | Value               | OS     | WMI Filter (Item-Level-Targeting): 
%pf_x86% | %programfiles%      |7 x86   | select * from Win32_OperatingSystem
                                          WHERE Version like "6.%" AND  
                                          ProductType="1" AND 
                                          NOT OSArchitecture = "64-bit"
%pf_x86% | %programfiles(x86)% |7,10 x64| select * from Win32_OperatingSystem
                                          WHERE  (Version like "6.%" OR 
                                          Version like "10.%") AND
                                          ProductType="1" AND 
                                          OSArchitecture = "64-bit"
%pf_x86% | %programfiles%      |XP x86  | select * from Win32_OperatingSystem 
                                          WHERE (Version like "5.1%") AND 
                                          ProductType="1"
%pf_x86% | C:\Programme (x86)  |XP x64  | select * from Win32_OperatingSystem 
                                          WHERE (Version like "5.2%") AND 
                                          ProductType="1" AND OSLanguage=1031
%pf_x64% | %programfiles%      |7,10 x64| select * from Win32_OperatingSystem
                                          WHERE Version like (Version like "6.%" OR 
                                          Version like "10.%") AND 
                                          ProductType="1" AND 
                                          OSArchitecture = "64-bit"
%pf_x64% | %programfiles%      |XP x64  | select * from Win32_OperatingSystem 
                                          WHERE (Version like "5.2%") AND 
                                          ProductType="1"
```

(OS Languages are outlined here: https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/appendix/OSLangCodes.htm)

[image]

## Outcome

This custom environment variable now allows me to configure exactly two shurtcuts per application - No matter which OS-Version is running on whatever architecture or language

```
Shortcut |Target               | Purpose
App 64   |%pf_x64%\App\app.exe | x64-app on any environment.
App 32   |%pf_x86%\App\app.exe | x86-app on any environment.
```

And if both exist - both shortcuts will be deployed.

#### Windows 7, 64bit, ML

[image]

#### Windows 7, 32bit, ML

[image]

#### Windows XP, 32 bit, ger

[image]

etc. pp.

Comment: Updated WMI-Filters For 10 - copy&paste error.